# Unable to build; undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, compilation, ffmpeg

In the process of trying to create an RTSP screen streaming server, I tried looking at CocoaSplit for an example.

Problem is, I can't get it to compile.

I have FFMpeg installed on my computer using Homebrew following FFMpeg's guide on https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/CompilationGuide/MacOSX .

But on compilation, Xcode is throwing out errors such as

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:

"_cmnMemAlloc", referenced from:_aac_encode_init in libavcodec.a(libvo-aacenc.o)
"_cmnMemCheck", referenced from:_aac_encode_init in libavcodec.a(libvo-aacenc.o)
"_cmnMemCopy", referenced from:_aac_encode_init in libavcodec.a(libvo-aacenc.o)
"_cmnMemFree", referenced from:_aac_encode_init in libavcodec.a(libvo-aacenc.o)
"_cmnMemSet", referenced from:_aac_encode_init in libavcodec.a(libvo-aacenc.o)
```

and so on.

The header search paths field in project settings has the directory of `/usr/local/include` in it.

What seems to be the problem here?

Answer (score 0):

Waaaay late to the party I know, but I just had the same problem and maybe my solution is useful to some other poor soul out there in the future.

The problem is that you are missing a library called `lib-aacenc`. Mine was located here (installed by Homebrew it seems):

`usr/local/Cellar/libvo-aacenc/0.1.3/lib/`

And I think it was done as part of installing ffmpeg via Homebrew. At least, if I do so:

`brew info ffmpeg`

I'm rewarded with this:

```
ffmpeg: stable 2.8, HEAD
Play, record, convert, and stream audio and video
https://ffmpeg.org/
/usr/local/Cellar/ffmpeg/2.8 (215 files, 47M) *
  Built from source with: --with-ffplay
From:     https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/blob/master/Library/Formula/ffmpeg.rb
==> Dependencies
Build: pkg-config ✔, texi2html ✔, yasm ✔
Recommended: x264 ✔, lame ✔, libvo-aacenc ✔, xvid ✔
Optional: faac ✘, fontconfig ✘, freetype ✔, theora ✘, libvorbis ✔, libvpx ✘, rtmpdump ✘, opencore-amr ✘, libass ✘, openjpeg ✘, speex ✘, schroedinger ✘, fdk-aac ✘, opus ✘, frei0r ✘, libcaca ✘, libbluray ✘, libsoxr ✘, libquvi ✘, libvidstab ✘, x265 ✘, openssl ✘, libssh ✘, webp ✘, zeromq ✘
==> Options
--with-faac
  Build with faac support
--with-fdk-aac
  Enable the Fraunhofer FDK AAC library
--with-ffplay
  Enable FFplay media player
--with-fontconfig
  Build with fontconfig support
--with-freetype
  Build with freetype support
--with-frei0r
  Build with frei0r support
--with-libass
  Enable ASS/SSA subtitle format
--with-libbluray
  Build with libbluray support
--with-libcaca
  Build with libcaca support
--with-libquvi
  Build with libquvi support
--with-libsoxr
  Enable the soxr resample library
--with-libssh
  Enable SFTP protocol via libssh
--with-libvidstab
  Enable vid.stab support for video stabilization
--with-libvorbis
  Build with libvorbis support
--with-libvpx
  Build with libvpx support
--with-opencore-amr
  Enable Opencore AMR NR/WB audio format
--with-openjpeg
  Enable JPEG 2000 image format
--with-openssl
  Enable SSL support
--with-opus
  Build with opus support
--with-rtmpdump
  Enable RTMP protocol
--with-schroedinger
  Enable Dirac video format
--with-speex
  Build with speex support
--with-theora
  Build with theora support
--with-tools
  Enable additional FFmpeg tools
--with-webp
  Enable using libwebp to encode WEBP images
--with-x265
  Enable x265 encoder
--with-zeromq
  Enable using libzeromq to receive commands sent through a libzeromq client
--without-lame
  Disable MP3 encoder
--without-libvo-aacenc
  Disable VisualOn AAC encoder
--without-qtkit
  Disable deprecated QuickTime framework
--without-x264
  Disable H.264 encoder
--without-xvid
  Disable Xvid MPEG-4 video encoder
--HEAD
  Install HEAD version
==> Caveats
FFmpeg has been built without libfaac for licensing reasons;
libvo-aacenc is used by default.
To install with libfaac, you can:
  brew reinstall ffmpeg --with-faac

You can also use the experimental FFmpeg encoder, libfdk-aac, or
libvo_aacenc to encode AAC audio:
  ffmpeg -i input.wav -c:a aac -strict experimental output.m4a
Or:
  brew reinstall ffmpeg --with-fdk-aac
  ffmpeg -i input.wav -c:a libfdk_aac output.m4a
```

And as you can see, you have to actually specify `--without-libvo-aacenc` to not have it installed.

But, yes, in short, if you start seeing linker errors about `lib-aacenc`, then it could be located somewhere in the vicinity of here:

`usr/local/Cellar/libvo-aacenc/0.1.3/lib/`

Comment: libvo-aacenc is a very poor AAC encoder, and support for it has recently been removed from FFmpeg. Because you are compiling anyway, I recommending using libfdk-aac instead. If you use that you can also remove the libfaac dependency. See [FFmpeg Wiki: AAC](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Encode/AAC) and [FFmpeg wiki: Compile/OS X](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/CompilationGuide/MacOSX) for some more info.

Comment: Thank you for your reply @LordNeckbeard, and thank you for the link. Knowing that this probably isn't the place to ask this, I'll take the liberty of asking anyway and hope that you have some pointers. I'm trying to write an OS X app that uses FFMPEG. As I cannot be sure that users have FFMPEG installed on their machines, I'm guessing that I'll have to include all the relevant `.a` files and header files into my project and setting up linker flags and header search paths. Do you know of anywhere where an ignorant iOS/OS X developer like me can read more about how to do this the right way?

Comment: You'll probably have to distribute a `ffmpeg` binary with your app (unless you're using the libraries?). Sorry, I'd help more if I could but count me among the iOS ignorant.

Comment: Thank you for your reply once again. I'm intending to build an OS X app that uses some functions from FFMPEG. So far I've copied the relevant `.a` files from the FFMPEG location `/usr/local/Cellar/FFMPEG/version/lib` and the header files from  `/usr/local/Cellar/FFMPEG/version/include` to directories in my own project and added linker settings for them, but it is cumbersome and I'm hoping I'm doing this the wrong way and that there is another and better way somewhere out there, documented, illustrated and everything, that I just haven't found, but I'll keep looking :-)

Answer (score 0):

you should add include and library path in project

i have testd ffmpeg with c++, refer to link:
https://medium.com/@mfkhao2009/set-up-ffmpeg-development-enviroment-on-macos-2523f7d3b2e8

add below to you cmake

```
find_path(AVCODEC_INCLUDE_DIR libavcodec/avcodec.h)
find_library(AVCODEC_LIBRARY avcodec)

find_path(AVFORMAT_INCLUDE_DIR libavformat/avformat.h)
find_library(AVFORMAT_LIBRARY avformat)

find_path(AVUTIL_INCLUDE_DIR libavutil/avutil.h)
find_library(AVUTIL_LIBRARY avutil)

find_path(AVDEVICE_INCLUDE_DIR libavdevice/avdevice.h)
find_library(AVDEVICE_LIBRARY avdevice)

include_directories(${AVCODEC_INCLUDE_DIR})
include_directories(${AVFORMAT_INCLUDE_DIR})
include_directories(${AVUTIL_INCLUDE_DIR})
include_directories(${AVDEVICE_INCLUDE_DIR})
link_libraries(${AVCODEC_LIBRARY})
link_libraries(${AVFORMAT_LIBRARY})
link_libraries(${AVUTIL_LIBRARY})
link_libraries(${AVDEVICE_LIBRARY})
```